# openGL simple 2d light

Tags: opengl, textures, lwjgl, light

I am making a simple pixel top-down game. And I want to add some simple lights there, but I don't know what the best way to do that. This image is an example of light what I want to realise. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlMf4.jpg 
When I googled that task, I saw only solutions for that kind of light.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVlYsGOkkyM 
But I need to increase a brightness of the texture part when the light source is near. How can I do this if I am using textures with `GL_QUADS` without UV?

Comment: for fixed pipeline (without shaders) you can either use [native OpenGL lights](https://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse872/tutorial3.html) set to point lights. Or use alpha textures + Blending for custom patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my response may not totally answer you question, but it will lead you down the right path.

It appears you are using immediate mode, this is now depreciated and changing to VBOs (vertex buffer objects) will make you life easier.

The lighting in the picture appears to be hand drawn. You cannot create that style of lighting exactly with even the best algorithm.

You really have two options to solve your problem, and both of them will require texture coordinates and shaders.

You could go with lightmaps, which use a pre generated texture multiplied over the texture of a quad. This is extremely fast, but requires some sort of tool to generate the lightmaps which might be a bit over your head at the moment.

Instead, learn shader based lighting. Many tutorials exist for 3d lighting but the principles remain the same for 2D.
Some Googling will get you the resources you need to implement shaders.
A basic distance based lighting algorithm will look like this:

```
GL_Color = texturecolor * 1.0/distance(light_position,world_position);
```

It multiplies the color of the texel by how far away the texel is from the light position. There are tutorials that go more into depth on this.

If you want to make the lighting look "retro" like in the first image,you can downsample the colors in a postprocesing step.